# How to run gcloud commands in flutter integration test?

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test

I want to run the gcloud commands in flutter integration test.

My use case is i need to get the access_token of firebase via `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` which is working locally on my terminal. Now i want to run the same command in flutter integration test either via shell script or using some package.!

Any helps highly appreciated. !

Answer (score 0):

You can generally achieve this by gc cloud client seceret key:

Your sell script ftl.sh will look like below:
......................................

```
gc_key=ewogIteyueueieiieie

setup_firebase_test_lab() {
  echo "setup firebase test lab"
  echo $gc_key >./gcloud_key_file.json
  gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=gcloud_key_file.json
  gcloud --quiet config set project project_name
}

setup_firebase_test_lab
echo "Running firebase test lab tests"
gcloud firebase test android run --type instrumentation --app APK_PATH/app-prod-debug.apk --test TEST_APK_PATH/androidTest.apk --device model=oriole,version=31,locale=en,orientation=portrait --timeout 45m
```

---

This will first setup your firesbase test lab and run tests